# Redis wrong EXPIRE in MULTI

Tags: docker, redis, raspberry-pi

With Redis, this script fails:

```
multi
sadd 1 1
expire 1 100
exec
smembers 1
...
(empty list or set)
```

It says that the set is empty.
I've put the expire to 100 seconds, which is more than enough for a script that runs in a fraction of second.
If I put the expire to 200 seconds, it works:

```
multi
sadd 1 1
expire 1 200
exec
smembers 1
...
1) "1"
```

Another point: if I remove the MULTI it works too:

```
sadd 1 1
expire 1 100
smembers 1
...
1) "1"
```

I execute it on a Raspberry PI. Is it a clock problem?
I use Redis docker version 6.0.

EDIT:
This looks fishy:

```
$ date
Mon Sep  6 18:41:13 CEST 2021
$ docker exec -it redis date
Thu May 21 19:18:40 CEST 2071
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be linked to this problem:
[corrupt date with redis:6-alpine on RasPi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091978/corrupt-date-with-redis6-alpine-on-raspi)

It's due to an oudated version of `libseccomp` in our Raspbian... Which conflicts with new versions of Redis.

Using a slightly older version of redis works, for instance redis:6.0.6-alpine3.12.